# Largest Rectangle in Histogram using stack

Tags: c++, data-structures

Hey friends i am solving this problem but i got an runtime error and not able to figure out that why i am getting this error for the input [0,0]

my code gives right answer if the input is not [0,0] in 0ms response time..

---

This question is related to the stack data structure. Here is a screenshot and the link of the question..
**link** - https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-rectangle-in-histogram/ 
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
and here is the error which i get with input [0,0]
[image: error screenshot]

---

**Here is my code** -

```
class Solution {
public:
    int largestRectangleArea(vector<int>& h) {
        vector<int> left, right;
        stack<pair<int, int>> l,r;
        //storing left smaller index
        for(int i = 0; i < h.size(); i++){
            if(l.empty()){
                left.push_back(-1);
                l.push({h[i], i});
            }else if(l.top().first < h[i]){
                left.push_back(l.top().second);
                l.push({h[i], i});
            }else if(!l.empty() && l.top().first > h[i]){
                while(!l.empty() && l.top().first > h[i]){
                    l.pop();
                }
                if(l.empty()){
                    left.push_back(-1);
                    l.push({h[i], i});
                }else{
                    left.push_back(l.top().second);
                    l.push({h[i], i});
                }
            }
        }
        //storing right smaller index
        for(int i = h.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(r.empty()){
                right.push_back(h.size());
                r.push({h[i], i});
            }else if(r.top().first < h[i]){
                right.push_back(r.top().second);
                r.push({h[i], i});
            }else if(!r.empty() && r.top().first > h[i]){
                while(!r.empty() && r.top().first > h[i]){
                    r.pop();
                }
                if(r.empty()){
                    right.push_back(h.size());
                    r.push({h[i], i});
                }else{
                    right.push_back(r.top().second);
                    r.push({h[i], i});
                }
            }
        }
        reverse(right.begin(), right.end());
        
        vector<int> ans;
        int find;
        for(int i = 0; i < h.size(); i++){
            find = (right[i] - left[i]) - 1;
            find = find*h[i];
            ans.push_back(find);
        }
        return *max_element(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if every element in `vector h` is the same, your code will crack. In your first 2 `for loop` has 3 `if` statements, when it runs into the second element in vector h, if `h[0] = h[1]` then all 3 if statements will not be satisfied, so `left` and `right` vector will only have 1 element, in the last `for loop` you run through all elements in `h`, which is bigger than 1, so your code cracked here.